# Assumptions on event raising

Tags: c#, events

Imagine the following class:

```
class A
{
     public event EventHandler AnyEvent;
}
```

You create an instance of class `A`, and attach some event handlers. Now if `AnyEvent` gets raised, I would not assume, that the event handlers are performed on another thread, than the thread I created the object. This would be of prime importance, if you created the object on a GUI thread, and the event handler performs operations on GUI elements. This would force me to use appropriate invocation patterns.

It really becomes evil, if you use interfaces defining events:

```
interface B
{
     event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}
```

Now one implementation could raise the event from the original thread, the next from a second thread. This can cause your application to successfully work with the one, and fail with the other implementation.

I think coding should always be transparent - this is not! And if I don't create another thread, I do not assume, that my methods are performed from any other than my *home* thread.

**Are there any aspects I did not consider?** Any that would invalidate my assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threading is the responsibility the consumer of the class, not the writer of the class, so your assumption is incorrect.

One should assume a class is not thread-safe unless it is documented to be thread-safe.  Even most built-in .NET classes are not thread safe unless they say they are.

It is up to the consumer of the class to be aware of threading.

Comment: Okay, I never heard, that I initially have to assume classes are not thread-safe. However, what do you think about the interface part of my question?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not something that can be enforced by an interface.  The best you can do is to document the interface in a certain way and assume the implementer will follow the guideline.  Abstractions will leak http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic with events. Events are handled on the thread that raises them. It has nothing to do with the thread that creates the object.

Comment: Then you need to clarify the question. You should also try to break it down, in order to reveal which false assumptions your question contains.

Comment: I think I already did that. Maybe you should read the second part again, that is regarding the interface.

Comment: You have not. I barely see a question in there. Only false assumptions.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I always have to dispatch event handlers to my own thread manually, because I never really know, if the implementation used another thread or not?

Comment: Yes. It's just a bad assumption. Don't make any assumptions.

Comment: So then, why it's a bad assumption? I think it is very paranoid, and will also blow up your code, if you assume new threads for every event.

Comment: No. Don't make any assumptions. Somebody is calling your code. You don't know who. Be prepared to be called by _anybody_. Be prepared to be called by someone who just wants to mess you up! Make sure your code works regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Calling events is just calling some method (or collection of methods) using a mechanism such as function pointers.

Events are completely oblivious to the thread that attached them, and don't have any other information that could lead to properly Invoking the methods on the right thread.

Maybe you are drawing your assumptions from COM days?

Answer (score 0):

Handler callbacks for events are on the same thread that raised the event.